# babel-plugin-react-css-modules does not support background images

Tags: webpack, babeljs, postcss, css-modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

> > After using css-modules, the background-image in scss will not work.
> >
> > Please, How to configure it correctly?

repo: https://github.com/pdsuwwz/Antd-app

## Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/script/components/redux-test/style.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/black-coffee.png' in '/Users/admin/Documents/zhike/github/myRepository/Antd-test/Antd-app/src/script/components/redux-test'
    at factory.create (/Users/admin/Documents/zhike/github/myRepository/Antd-test/Antd-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:821:10)
    at factory (/Users/admin/Documents/zhike/github/myRepository/Antd-test/Antd-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:397:22)
    at resolver (/Users/admin/Documents/zhike/github/myRepository/Antd-test/Antd-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
    at asyncLib.parallel (/Users/admin/Documents/zhike/github/myRepository/Antd-test/Antd-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
```

.babelrc:

```
...
["babel-plugin-react-css-modules", {
  "generateScopedName": "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]",
  "webpackHotModuleReloading": true,
  "filetypes": {
    ".scss": {
      "syntax": "postcss-scss"
    }
  }
}]
...
```

scss:

```
.test-relativeimg{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("./assets/black-coffee.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

webpack

```
{
  test: /\.scss/,
  use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]", {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      ident: 'postcss',
      sourceMap: true,
      config: {
        path: resolve('postcss.config.js')
      }
    },
  },
  "sass-loader"],
  exclude: resolve('node_modules'),
  include: resolve('src')
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("autoprefixer")({
    browsers: ['last 2 versions']
  }), require("cssnano")()]
}
```

Comment: In your repo, where is the assets folder?

Comment: https://github.com/pdsuwwz/Antd-app/tree/master/src/script/components/redux-test, here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because Webpack needs a loader for the `png` file.

> You need url-loader || file-loader to get images/assets into your bundle

[More information](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/160#issuecomment-271077492)

Comment: The problem is solved, it seems that `cssnano` has affected css-modules.